# How can I stop a UIView resizing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

Basically, a UIView is automatically resizing when its parent view is resized - but I don't want this to happen.

Specifically, I'm resizing the height of a UITableView cell, and I don't want the corresponding cell.backgroundView to resize with it.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the answer was:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     cell.backgroundView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
[cell setAutoresizesSubviews:NO];
```